# Looking for advice on applying textures to 3D models at run time

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d

I'm working on a project that requires user generated images to be applied to various 3D models (mugs, t-shirts etc). I've explored numerous applications, (Pyglet, Blender, Panda to name a few), and am looking for ideas / guidance as to the best approach.

Appears to me that the world of 3D modelling has quite a steep learning curve (looking at you GL), just looking to invest my time wisely.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you plan to allow live manipulation of these object with a 3D viewer (e.g. OpenGL), or just render images of the texture mapped objects, e.g. like Cafepress previews?

Comment: Just rendering images for now, perhaps 3D viewer in the future but it's not pressing

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you're interested in replacing textures on-the-fly, you should render your objects as UV maps.

UV maps specify the pixel offset within the texture so that once a texture is chosen, it is a simple process of table lookup for filling in the texture.

You might consider rendering at double the resolution and *after* applying reduce the image size. This will anti-alias any discontinuities.